# Trying to Iterate rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate rows of a data frame using python. Let me explain.

I have a data frame:

| Rows | column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Jacob | Smith |
| 2 | Cat | Jumped | Broom |
| 3 | Dog | Likes | Steak |

I need to iterate each row of the data frame using a loop ( I was thinking a For or While loop):

```
`For i in *data frame* ['column 1']:

    print (i+1)`
```

So that my loop iterates each row of dataframe in column 1, output would be:

John

Cat

Dog

Instead I'm getting errors:
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found`

Comment: ``for i in df['column 1']: print(i)``

Comment: any idea how I can get my for loop to iterate the rows tho?  when I do as you suggested, it only prints the column header.

Comment: ``for i in range(len(df['column 1'])): print(df['column 1'][i])`` is the simplest way in my opinion

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.  I think this makes sense to me too.

Comment: one more question too... do you think iterrows() would achieve the same result? or is that something different?

Comment: you can achieve the same result with iterrows. On a side note, I'd like to remind you that iterating through each element in a df is probably not the best idea.